# Checking date and its patten with expected pattern

Tags: java, date, datetimeoffset

I have a date and it's supposed pattern  in string.

```
//True
String date ="2012-10-12 12:01:10.10.150";
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS";

//False
String date ="2012-10-12 12:01:10.150";
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
```

Now,i wanted to know whether the date variable has a proper date which satisfies a given pattern in string. In the above example True/False which I shows is the expected result.

I have tried with SimpleDateFormat(if it throws ParseException),but it will not going to work for 2nd example.

```
public boolean isValidDate(String date, String pattern) {
    if (date == null)
        return false;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    try {
        dateFormat.parse(date.trim());
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: use a regex to test for the expected pattern

Comment: How did you use `SimpleDateFormt`?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern); and then i parse it.

Comment: I tried your code and I get `true` for the first date/pattern and `false` for the second date/pattern. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Sorry...2nd example was incorrect.Now i have modified that.Can you look into it.

Comment: What do you mean that you have modified it? I don't see any updates to the question...

Comment: Sorry..it was not affected.Now i did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use both regex and SimpleDateFormat to achieve what you want

```
boolean validate(String date, String pattern) throws ParseException {
    String regex = pattern.replaceAll("\\w", "\\\\d").replace(".", "\\.");
    if (!date.matches(regex)) {
        return false;
    }
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    try {
        sdf.parse(date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Ya,i think so.But in this case my date and pattern are dynamic.These are comeing from some property file.So how to handel this requirement.

Comment: Yes...that's what i am looking for...but can you tell why you have used .replace(".", "\\.") at last ?

Comment: because . is a meta character in regex which means any character, so it should be escaped

Answer (score 1):

Use `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` as the pattern for the second date.

```
String date = "2012-10-12 12:01:10";
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date parse = sdf.parse(date);
```

The capital `S` stands for milliseconds which your second string doesn't have. [See the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: It's not about which pattern i wanted to use.I wanted to check whether given pattern satisfy given date in string format.

Comment: It is the other way round. Check if an input satisfies a pattern.

Comment: That's what my question is..how to check it ?

Comment: My code does exactly that: it checks if `date` matches `pattern`.

Comment: But your code will not work for my 2nd example right? I am passing String date ="2012-10-12 12:01:10"; String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS"; but it should return false for me.

Comment: Using your second date and pattern throws a `java.text.ParseException` which exactly as it should be. Catch this exception and you are done.

Comment: Sorry...that example was incorrect.Now i have modified that one.Can you please look into it.

Answer (score 1):

From the `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` Java doc:

> ...parsing does not necessarily use all characters up to the end of the
>   string...

This means if your date is longer that the pattern it will still produce a valid `Date` instance. The other way around (e.g. your second example) the pattern is longer (more detailed) that the given date string, hence it doesn't produce a `Date`. Use this instead for your second example:

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I thing you pople are confused.I have edited my question.I want the method as in question which is incorrect for the 2nd example.